# How to specify center of Shape in Kinetic JS

Tags: kineticjs

I created a pie and added gradient in it using drawFunc method and I want to move that pie in the center of Kinetic JS stage but it rotates somewhere else. My code is as follows:

```
                 var gradientPie = new Kinetic.Shape({

                    drawFunc: function(context) {
                        var startingAngle = (60 * Math.PI)/180;
                        var arcSize = (60 * Math.PI)/180;
                        var endingAngle = startingAngle + arcSize;
                        context.beginPath();
                        context.moveTo(500, 375);
                        context.arc(500, 375, 250,
                                startingAngle, endingAngle, false);
                        context.closePath();

                        var gradient = context.createLinearGradient(500, 375, 500+250, 375+250);

                        gradient.addColorStop(0, '#fff');
                        gradient.addColorStop(0.25, '#99FF99');
                        gradient.addColorStop(0.5, '#00CC33');
                        gradient.addColorStop(1, '#009900');
                        context.fillStyle = gradient;

                        context.fill();
                        this.fill(context);
                        this.stroke(context);
                    },
                    stroke: "#006400",
                    strokeWidth: 1

                });

                layer.add(gradientPie);

                /*
                 * leave center point positioned
                 * at the default which is the top left
                 * corner of the rectangle
                 */
                var blueRect = new Kinetic.Rect({
                    x: 500,
                    y: 375,
                    width: 100,
                    height: 50,
                    fill: "#00D2FF",
                    stroke: "black",
                    strokeWidth: 4
                });
                layer.add(blueRect);

                stage.add(layer);

                // one revolution per 4 seconds
                var angularSpeed = Math.PI / 2;
                stage.onFrame(function(frame) {
                    var angleDiff = frame.timeDiff * angularSpeed / 1000;
                    gradientPie.setOffset(500, 375);
                    gradientPie.rotate(angleDiff);
                    blueRect.rotate(angleDiff);
                    layer.draw();
                });
```

I am able to move the blue rect and similarly I want to move my gradientPie as weel at same center points but its not moving. Thank you, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I got it working, I added these 2 lines and the gradient pie moved to the center rotating.
                        gradientPie.setPosition(500, 375);
                        gradientPie.setOffset(500, 375);

Comment: Can you please post your answer and mark it as correct to push it out of the 'unanswered' list